# Copying MSOnline PowerShell module as a workaround

Tags: powershell, module, installation

I am in a tricky situation where I need to install the MSOnline PowerShell module on a PC and it needs to install NuGet first. Unfortunately, the company firewall does not trust the NuGet website, so the PowerShell cmdlets fail at installation.

I was wondering whether I could simply copy a directory containing the MSOnline module from one PC to my target PC. Is this a viable workaround? Or is there another workaround?

I understand that ideally, I should try to have the website whitelisted, but there is a question of timing here.

Comment: From a computer that has access you could use the `Save-Module` cmdlet to save the module to a path, then copy that folder to the machine in question that's blocked. Then you can either place the folder in the `$env:PSModulePath`, or load it explicitly with the full path to the folder.

Comment: Woaw, excellent. You should create an answer so I can approve it. I'll try it and let you know if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As exlpained in the comment of @TheMadTechnician you can copy the module from the `$env:PSMdulePath` the your requested target machines.

If you've multiple machines for module distribtion you can setup your own private Powershell gallery via a network share as explained [here](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-05-30-Powershell-your-first-PSScript-repository/) (if that's possible in your company). Based on that multiple machines can use the `Get-PSRepository`, `Find-Module -Repository MyRepository`, `Install-Module -Name MyModule -Repository MyRepository` ,.. cmdlets for module administration. I'm using this a private Powershell gallery to distribute some Git tools about multiple dev-machines. You could also publish own Powershell modules in this gallery, in the background NuGet is used. So your machine with access to NuGet could store the newest module via `Save-Module` (maybe via a background job) and re-publish it to your private gallery.

You should also check if the `MSOnline`module has any `RequiredPackages` that you also need to copy. You can do this via (where I used `PowerShellGet` as example):

```
 PS C:\> (Get-Module -ListAvailable | ? Name -eq PowerShellGet ).RequiredModules

 ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
 ---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
 Script     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement
```

Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From a computer that has access you could use the `Save-Module` cmdlet to save the module to a path, then copy that folder to the machine in question that's blocked. Then you can either place the folder in the `$env:PSModulePath`, or load it explicitly with the full path to the folder.

On a computer that has access to the PowerShell Gallery you can run:

```
Find-Module MSOnline|Save-Module -Path $home\Downloads
```

Then copy the MSOnline folder from your downloads folder on that computer to the target computer, and place it in one of the folders listed in `$env:PSModulePath`, or when you want to load the module you can do it explicitly by defining the path to the module.